# searchView.setOnQueryTextListener() not executed, and background white with white text

Tags: android, searchview

I created a data search function using the SearchView component, everything went normally when I run it on virtual android with API version> = 19 in android studio, and when I run it on this android device it also runs normally, but some devices display a white background search view with white text i tried change background-color to transparent but still displayed white color and searchView.setOnQueryTextListener() are not executed when the enter key is pressed. I have done a search on google but did not get the right search results

Comment: show the screen shot, the i will understand clearly

Comment: sorry my problem was resolved

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp" />


  searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {


            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            searchData(newText.toLowerCase().trim());

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I tried but it didn't work